# Allow view access to current user and admin

Tags: views, 8, users

I'm creating a view to list user sessions statistics. (Data selected from table myuserstat, there is UID field, myuserstat rows is not a Content Type, just table)

I want to make access url like /mystat/{user}, to list data of specified user.

How can I allow users to see their own stat, and admins see all users stat?
For now i only found how to limit to the current user:
contextual filter->UID->Provide default value->logged user id.
But in that case, how to allow admins to view all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another view or a page within same view with path /mystat or path can be different without using contextual filters. And in page seetting option in view choose access from none to role and select admin role.

Comment: Yes, thats straightforward way, but i thought there is more right/drupal way.

Comment: another way of doing this is by using hook_view_query_alter where you can  remove contextual filters in case of uid = 1;

Comment: @Vovka you're over thinking this. This is exactly how you should do it. Ever heard of [KISS](https://www.google.ca/search?q=KISS&oq=KISS&aqs=chrome..69i57.967j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=keep+it+simple+stupid)? Not the rock band.